# IE 9 / 8 sub menu is missing

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have used the same formation theme from wordpress for the 2 site installs :

[www.indulgences.asia/en/][1]

[www.millionaires.asia/chi/][2]

The menu works fabulously on all browsers with `www.millionaires.asia/chi/` but this is not the case for the `www.indulgences.asia/en/` as the submenu is hidden in IE 8/9. I have tried `z-index`, `overflow`, removing the entire content leaving only header, siderbar and footer, but the submenu still remains hidden in IE 8 / 9. I have also compared the 2 codes to see what went wrong but both codes are very similar. I tried to see if the carousel was inhibiting , but like i said i stripped every thing down to header, sidebar , footer and the menus still remain hidden.

I am getting exasperated. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Write your code in fiddle to make it clear

Comment: sorry suraj I have never used fiddle before. I am not a programmer. I am more of a trial and error with variables person.

Comment: Please don't use live URLs in your question; these may be resolved tomorrow, and then anybody coming to this question will have no idea what the original problem was. Create a permanent demo of the issue to avoid link-rot.

Comment: @mcth80 goto jsfiddle.net and paste your code their and save and then give us that link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear all thanks for the help. I would like to post the answer which I painfully did line by line addition to the base css files.

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#a3a0a3', GradientType=0 );

This screwed up my menu bar. Perhaps IE 9 and below couldn't render it. Once I removed it, problem was gone.